# Escaping/Replacing .cshtml comment tags in string

Tags: c#, razor

I have a textbox in which the client can input text regulations which he can modify with HTML/CSS. The problem is that a client has inserted a comment tag "<!--" but hasn't closed it so it breaks the rest of the page. What would be a smart way to avoid that?
The only thing I came up with is

```
string someString = "<!-- <div></div><p></p>";
model.Regulations= someString.Replace("<!--", "").Replace("--!>", "").Replace("&lt;!--", "").Replace("--!&gt;", "").Replace("@*", "").Replace("*@", "");
```

This doesn't look very clean to me. What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [HTML Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex).

This would allow you to load the HTML into an HtmlDocument and check for errors:

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();

htmlDoc.LoadHtml("<!-- <div></div><p></p>");

if(htmlDoc.ParseErrors.Any())
    //Now you can display an error and have user correct it

foreach (var error in htmlDoc.ParseErrors)
{
    // Additionally you can get each error to display back to user
}
```

If you detect an error, make it a validation issue on the input textbox and have the user correct it. I think trying to auto correct issues such as this is going to be an exercise in futility and reinforces bad habits and/or lack of knowledge on the user's part.